# Laravel 5 Unique form validation ignore id / slug

Tags: php, laravel-5, unique, rules, slug

These are my rules in my class:

```
class AppointmentsController extends Controller
{
    protected $rules = [
        'appointment' => ['required', 'min:5'],
        'slug'        => ['required', 'unique:appointments'],
        'description' => ['required'],
        'date'        => ['required', 'date_format:"Y-m-d H:i"'],
    ];
```

This is in the laravel official docs:

> Sometimes, you may wish to ignore a given ID during the unique check.
>   For example, consider an "update profile" screen that includes the
>   user's name, e-mail address, and location. Of course, you will want to
>   verify that the e-mail address is unique. However, if the user only
>   changes the name field and not the e-mail field, you do not want a
>   validation error to be thrown because the user is already the owner of
>   the e-mail address. You only want to throw a validation error if the
>   user provides an e-mail address that is already used by a different
>   user. To tell the unique rule to ignore the user's ID, you may pass
>   the ID as the third parameter:

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,'.$user->id.',user_id'
```

I tried using this in my rules:

```
'slug'        => ['required', 'unique:appointments,id,:id'],
```

This indeed ignores the current row BUT it ignores it completely. What I want to accomplish is, I want it to ignore the current row only if the slug is unchanged. When it is changed to something that is already unique in another row, I want it to throw an error.

Comment: try it this way: `'slug'        => ['required', 'unique:appointments,slug,:id']`

Comment: Yeah I shoud've mentioned that I tried that, no luck. My guess is though that it should work like that, so I need to figure out why it doesn't. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: why are you putting this in a controller ? It should go in a custom request class which cant hen be used in a controller. Not sure if this is causing the issue.

Answer (score 13):

The Unique validator works like that

```
unique:table,column,except,idColumn
```

So in your case, you can do it like that:

Get the id you want to validate against, you can get it from the route or with any other way that works for you; something like that

```
$id = $this->route('id');

'slug'        => ['required','unique:appointments,slug,'.$id],
```

Comment: FYI - if you have a custom user id column name (such as 'user_id' instead of 'id'), the rule will look like this : 'email' => ['required','email','unique:user_table_name,email_col_name,'.$user->user_id .',user_id' ]

Answer (score 0):

For example we need to update contact info into Users table. 
In my model User I created this static method:

```
static function getContactDataValidationRules( $idUserToExcept ) {
    return [
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email,' . $idUserToExcept,
        'pec' => 'required|email|max:255',
        'phone' => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/|min:8|max:20',
        'mobile' => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/|min:8|max:20',
        'phone2' => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/|min:8|max:20',

        'recovery_email' => 'required|email|max:255',
    ];
}
```

and in my UsersController, into the method that update User I've:

```
$id = $request->input('id');
$request->validate(User::getContactDataValidationRules( $id ));
```

:-)